# Opening cPanel (web host server) in Adobe AIR Application

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am working on application to open cPanel (web host server) in Adobe AIR. I know how to open a web page in Adobe AIR, but I don't know how to open cPanel with username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be like that:

```
html.location = "http://" + txtDomain.text.toString() + ":2095/login/?user=" + txtUsername.text.toString() + "&pass=" + txtPassword.text.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mudasir just observe when you log in to CPANEL normally how the get variables are passed. You can do this using the open source tool fiddler (maybe not open source but it is free, I'm sure of that). Then just modify the URL inside AIR to include the username and password as get variables.